# PHP - If in string without leaving the string on str_replace()

Tags: php, string, if-statement, str-replace

```
$str = '<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-danger">Present Room Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="form-present-room-type" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="PREMIUM" '.( ("@form-present-room-type@" == "PREMIUM") ? "selected" : "").'>PREMIUM</option>
            <option value="SINGLE" '.( ("@form-present-room-type@" == "SINGLE") ? "selected" : "").'>SINGLE</option>
            <option value="DOUBLE" '.( ("@form-present-room-type@" == "DOUBLE") ? "selected" : "").'>DOUBLE</option>
            <option value="TRIPLE" '.( ("@form-present-room-type@" == "TRIPLE") ? "selected" : "").'>TRIPLE</option>                                    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>';
```

I questioned it the last time, and I figured out that when I make the `if` outside the option tag like the above code, the `@form-present-room-type@` value was not changed that means `@form-present-room-type` is not equal with `PREMIUM` or any of the `option` values. But when I put it inside the option tag. Like this `<option value="PREMIUM" (@form-present-room-type@ == PREMIUM ? selected : "")>PREMIUM</option>` he will get the `@form-present-room-type@` value, BUT it just returns string like this `<option value="PREMIUM" (premium="=" premium="" ?="" selected="" :="" "")="">PREMIUM</option>`. Cause I want it to be replaced with certain string like: `str_replace('@form-present-room-type@','PREMIUM',$str);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a cycle:

```
$options = ['', 'PREMIUM', 'SINGLE', 'DOUBLE', 'TRIPLE'];
$form_present_room_type = 'SINGLE';

$str = '';
foreach($options as $opt)
{
  $str.= '<option value="'.$opt.'"'.($form_present_room_type === $opt ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$opt.'</option>';
}
$str = '<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="text-danger">Present Room Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="form-present-room-type" required>'
.$str.'</select>
    </div>
</div>';
```